# Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY093) SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to select the `user_id` of all posts whos `id` is the current index in the while loop and whose `vote` is `1` and turn it into a numerical array .

But,it keeps giving me this error:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY093)
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select `user_id` from `laravellikecomment_likes` where (`item_id` = 1 and `vote` = ?))
```

I dunno what to do now.Here is my code(part of it):

```
$db='laravellikecomment_likes';


  $allposts= DB::table($db)->where('vote','!=',0)->get()->pluck('user_id');
  $allposts = $allposts->toArray();

  $tn=count($allposts);
  $ai=0;
  $user=Auth::id();

  while ($ai <= $tn) {
     $recclist=array();
     $current=array_keys($allposts,$ai);
     $id=1;
     $wl=DB::table($db)->where(function ($query) use ($current, $id) {
        $query->where('item_id', '=', $current);
        $query->where('vote','=',$id);
    })->pluck('user_id');
```

Comment: What is the overall problem that you are trying to solve? Maybe it could be done in just 1 query - could you clarify the overall aim please?

Comment: @party-ring I'm sorry....I don't get it

Comment: Can you explain your question clearly please

Comment: @party-ring I am new to laravel and I am trying to select the user_id of all posts whose id is the current index in the while loop and whose vote is 1 and turn it into a numerical array . to create a reccomendation engine .I am using the above posted query but hat isn't working.So pls what is the correct way ?

Comment: Why are you using a while loop? What should the numerical array contain?

Comment: @party-ring because I am looping over all the posts......i think am makin a big mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193146/discussion-between-party-ring-and-titox-d-boss).

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown has to do with your query

```php
$wl=DB::table($db)->where(function ($query) use ($current, $id) {
    $query->where('item_id', '=', $current); # This line is the culprit
    $query->where('vote','=',$id);
})->pluck('user_id');
```

The error thrown, `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid Parameter number` hints a parameter is wrong. In this case, you're trying to use an `array` where the `Query Builder` expects an `integer` or a `string`.

If you want to use an array, use `whereIn` instead of `where`, like so:

```php
$wl=DB::table($db)->where(function ($query) use ($current, $id) {
    $query->whereIn('item_id', $current); # Use whereIn to deal with arrays
    $query->where('vote', '=', $id);
})->pluck('user_id');
```